# shares-admin crashes when trying to add a share

Tags: xubuntu, samba

I'm running a fresh installation of xubuntu 16.10 and when clicking the "Add" button or the "Users" tab in `shares-admin` I get the following error:

```
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
[1]    31900 segmentation fault  sudo shares-admin
```

I've tried launching with sudo and as a normal user and using the "Unlock" button, same issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: This could be related to this long standing [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1467588) Have you tried uninstalling and re-installing [gnome-system-tools](http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/gnome-system-tools) which is the package that contains `shares-admin` ?

Comment: @ElderGeek good idea, gave it a shot, no change though :(

Comment: Have you confirmed that you aren't experiencing RAM errors by running [`memtest86+`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/zesty/+package/memtest86+)? Have you checked the [smart status](http://askubuntu.com/questions/528072/how-can-i-check-the-smart-status-of-a-drive-on-ubuntu-14-04-through-16-10/528077#528077) of your drive? These steps will help rule out common hardware causes

Comment: @ElderGeek yeah, all is well on both memory and disks.

Comment: I have the exact same problem

Comment: Here is a bug report about it and the issue still happens with 20.04.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-system-tools/+bug/1791786

Answer (score -2):

from terminal

1 sudo apt-get update
2 sudo apt-get install samba
3 sudo nano /etc/samba/smb.conf 
4 add to config next lines 
[share] 
comment = Ubuntu File Server Share
path = /home/ubuntu/ubuntu (place of your share)
browsable = yes
guest ok = yes
read only = no
create mask = 7777

Save changes in the file and create folder
sudo mkdir -p /home/ubuntu/ubuntu 
sudo chown nobody.nogroup /home/ubuntu/ubuntu

init 6 (reboot system)

After all this operations you will your share from any OS

Comment: I can setup a samba share using config without issue, my problem is with shares-admin having a segfault. Thanks though.