# How to fix "Segmentation failed" on "shares-admin"?

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to share files on network, but whenever I run "shares-admin", the following error occurs:

[image]

I already tried to install the samba UI but the same error occurs with it as well. Already reinstalled following some tips that I found on google, but to no avail.

How do I fix it?

My system is xubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: PS: [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/854668/shares-admin-crashes-when-trying-to-add-a-share) doesn't help me

Comment: Your issue seems either a duplicate or a bug report.